# Well-Ordering Theorem without Axiom of Regularity

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Personally, I am not fond of the Axiom of Regularity. Some alternative models in set theory use the negation of the Axiom of Regularity as an axiom (non well-founded theories). I am curious if the Well-Ordering Theorem is provable in this theories — I greatly suspect that the answer is *no* but would appreciate any kind of insight in this matter.

Comment: Can you be clear about what you mean by the well ordering theorem. Do you mean that every set can be well ordered, which is equivalent to the axiom of choice, and cannot be proven.

Comment: @Rene: The OP rejects regularity, not choice. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no actual appeal to the axiom of regularity in the usual proof of the well-ordering theorem, assuming the axiom of choice.

Instead we invoke the power set and replacement axioms in quite a strong way. The transfinite recursion is not applied on $\in$, but rather on the ordinals. And even without the axiom of regularity (at least in the presence of replacement), we have the same ordinal structure.

Of course, if you reject the axiom of choice as well, then this is no longer true. If you reject replacement, then things become slightly trickier, but we can use separation instead. If you reject that as well, then perhaps you should list the axioms you allow.

It should be noted that Zermelo in his initial set theory didn't have neither replacement nor regularity. But it sufficed to prove the well-ordering theorem just the same.

(Something that might be proved useful is A.R.D Mathias' paper "The Strength of the Mac Lane Set Theory" in which there is a table of set theories, their assumptions and some consequences, there he points out that the equivalence of the axiom of choice and the well-ordering theorem is provable in a weak system he denotes as $\sf M_0$.)

Comment: Can you sketch a proof that AC implies the well-ordering theorem in Z? I'm interested in how it can be proved without Replacement. Thanks!

Comment: Easily. It's exactly the same proof as usual, except that instead of ordinals we use a well-ordering that is given by Hartogs' theorem, that is a particular subset of $\mathcal P^3(X)$, for a given set $X$. Then use that to define a well-ordering, along with a choice function, and the recursion does not use Replacement, since it is all bounded within the Cartesian product of some large enough sets. And again, as I wrote, Zermelo proved that AC implies WO long before Replacement or Regularity came around.

Comment: @user123: In my opinion, a conceptually better proof of the well-ordering theorem in ZC is [this tower-based one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/44058?m=55470875#55470875), where the key idea is simply that if every well-ordered tower is built using the same choice function then they all agree so you can combine them all.